# Tokenize from a textfile reading into an array in C

Tags: c, text, file, tokenize

How do you tokenize when you read from a file in C?

*textfile:*

PES 2009;Konami;DVD 3;500.25; 6

Assasins Creed;Ubisoft;DVD;598.25; 3

Inferno;EA;DVD 2;650.25; 7

```
char *tokenPtr;

fileT = fopen("DATA2.txt", "r"); /* this will not work */
  tokenPtr = strtok(fileT, ";");
  while(tokenPtr != NULL ) {
  printf("%s\n", tokenPtr);
  tokenPtr = strtok(NULL, ";");
}
```

Would like it to print out:

PES 2009

Konami

.

.

.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
main()
{
    FILE *f;
    char s1[200],*p;
    f = fopen("yourfile.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(s1, 200, f))
    {
```

```
while (fgets(s1, 200, f))
{

    p=strtok(s1, ";\n");

    do
    {
        printf ("%s\n",p);
    }
    while(p=strtok(NULL,";\n"));
}
```

}

the 200 char size is just an example of course

Comment: this will take into account also the newline at the end of each row and will handle it correctly

Answer (score 0):

You must read the file content into a buffer, e.g. line by line using `fgets` or similar. Then use `strtok` to tokenize the buffer; read the next line, repeat until EOF.

Answer (score 0):

[`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) accepts a `char *` and a `const char *` as arguments. You're passing a `FILE *` and a `const char *` (after implicit conversion).

You need to read a string from the file and pass that string to the function.

Pseducode:

```
fopen();
while (fgets()) {
    strtok();
    /* Your program does not need to tokenize any further,
     * but you could now begin another loop */
    //do {
        process_token();
    //} while (strtok(NULL, ...) != NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using strtok is a BUG. Try strpbrk(3)/strsep(3) OR strspn(3)/strcspn(3).